# tag_edit_form_fields nor edit_tag_form_fields actions working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags, editor

In Wordpress,

When adding a custom field to a category, the following actions work as intended:

`category_add_form_fields`

`category_edit_form_fields`

For tags, however, things are not as straightforward nor do they behave the same.

The action `tag_add_form_fields` does not work but swapping "tag" and "add" to `add_tag_form_fields` does.

The action `tag_edit_form_fields` does not work either. When I change `tag_edit_form_fields` to the deprecated `add_edit_form_fields` the edit form appears to break and the save button is no longer created, and the function is never fired. At least something happens here, but it's not clear exactly what is happening.

Does anyone know how to add custom fields to WordPress tags? I'm looking for a code solution, not a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Garrette Hyder, of Wordpress.org, for helping steer me in the right direction here.

The correct actions for the edit form for the tag taxonomy in wordpress is:

`edit_tag_form_fields`

This action takes only one parameter, not two. My fatal error was caused by the extra parameter on my function.